# ion-item clickable properties not working (Ionic 4)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

**BACKGROUND:**
I have a dashboard for my app with 3 ion-items, I want them to be clickable so as someone clicks/taps on the item it will navigate to a different page.

Here is a screenshot to give a better understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMubO.jpg

Here is a link to my github repo with all the files: https://github.com/jamesslater/boutiquesolicitors

**PROBLEM:**
To do this I've been trying to call a method which routes to the correct page. However, while testing with a console.log I have noticed both (click) and href **do not work at all**.

Can someone please explain how I can get this working? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**RELEVANT CODE:**

*dashboard.page.html*

```
<div class="nav-wrapper" style="background: white;">
<ion-header class="navbar">

    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="logout()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" color="white" name="log-out"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-img src="assets/logo.png"></ion-img>


</ion-header>
 </div>
<ion-content padding text-center>
  <div class="profile">
  <ion-avatar>
<img src="assets/user.png">
</ion-avatar>
<h1>Hello Richard,</h1>
<ion-label>How can we help you today?</ion-label>
  </div>


    <ion-item (click)="search()">
      <ion-icon name="search" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Search for a service</ion-label>    
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
    <ion-icon name="paper" slot="start"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>View our latest news</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="card" slot="start"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Pay a bill</ion-label>
</ion-item>


  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
      <ion-tab-button tab="about">
       <ion-icon name="information-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>About Us</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
      <ion-tab-button href="members/dashboard">

        <ion-icon color="blue" name="home"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Dashboard</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
      <ion-tab-button tab="contact">
        <ion-icon name="contacts"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Contact Us</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

*dashboard.page.ts*

```
import { AuthenticationService } from './../../services/authentication.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.page.scss'],
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {
error = this.error; 
  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  logout() {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    // this.authService.logout();
  }

  search() {
    console.log('clicked');
    this.router.navigate(['members/services']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ,maybe i have a solution , but i'm not sure. try to set the ion-item z-index to 100

Comment: It still is not clickable, thanks anyway

Comment: I have done a test on your project, i didn't change nothing, only add (click) event like you , and for me works. this is weird :/ .

Comment: Hmm that is pretty weird. Does not work on Chrome dev tools or the Ionic DevApp for me.

Comment: that's working fine. You are looking something else might be.     <ion-item (click)="searchForService()">
      <ion-icon name="search" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Search for a service</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

Comment: Still not working for me :(

Comment: Your code doesn't have any (click) event `<ion-item>`, works fine for us after adding `(click)` on `<ion-item>`. like `<div class="items">
    <ion-item (click)="someMethod()">
      <ion-icon name="search" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Search for a service</ion-label>
    </ion-item>` Similarly added methods for the rest ion-item as well and worked fine.

Comment: That is because those github files are not my latest. The source code I've included in the question is what I have as of the present. I have (click)="search()" which calls the search method in the relative typescript file. For me, it does not work.

Comment: I have just updated the github files. Any testing/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: lemme try it again

Comment: Perhaps clickable ion-items and ion-tabs cannot exist on the same page? idk but that is all I've added since my last GitHub upload

Comment: Commented out the tabs and it works. Can confirm this seems to be the issue. Maybe a bug from Ionic dev team?

Comment: @JamesSlater  I have played a lot with your code and  found solution for your problem but didn't find cause , may be its from ionic side, look like ion-tabs and ion-items do not go along, You have to take tabs to separate page. Easy solution would be that create new ionic app using `ionic start appname tabs`, It separate tabs page from other content pages and works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have stated, ion items and ion tabs do not work in unison for some unknown reason. Wouldn't be known to the usual developer as this is a strange use case (which nobody else has picked up on above). Good thing I saw this question, otherwise you'd **NEVER** get this sorted mate. Surprised you even managed to consider this as one of the factors, well done for that one, really helps with the resolution for this:

Best way to go about doing this: Use a transparent ion-button inside of an ion item.

**HTML/IONIC Code For Button:**

```
    <div class="items">
   <ion-item detail> 
     <ion-button fill="clear" class="itemBtns" (click)="search()">Search for a service</ion-button>
     <ion-icon name="search" slot="start"></ion-icon> 
     <!-- <ion-label>Search for a service</ion-label>  -->
    </ion-item>
```

This creates a 'click zone' which is the way of bypassing the issue of not being able to use ion items and ion tabs at the same time.

**CSS for button:**

```
.itemBtns {
color: black;
font-size: 100%;
padding-right: 100%;  }
```

With a combination of the 'fill' property on the button in the HTML code, this makes the button invisible and should act as a hyperlink that spans the whole section of the ion item.

Please mark this as the correct answer if I have helped you. If not, let me know and I will offer further assistance. :)

Comment: Wow, thank you! I just got finished copying and pasting your code and to be honest I wasn't expecting much luck! This worked a charm I can't even tell the difference between before and after. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With ionic 5 you can add property button to ion-item and click event will work:

```
<ion-item button (click)="search()">
      <ion-icon name="search" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Search for a service</ion-label>    
  </ion-item>
```